# How to specify url for $resource for oData v4

Tags: angularjs, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm following [damienbod's series on webapi and odata4](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/getting-started-with-web-api-and-odata-v4/) where the odata url to query a single product would be:

```
http://localhost/odata/Products(5)
```

The question is, how do I structure my $resource url in angular to map to this url?  I've tried

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/odata/Products(:id)"
```

but this breaks when I want to query the collection, in which case the generated url is

```
http://localhost/odata/Products()
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/odata/Products
```

Please advise how I need to construct the $resource url for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just override the URL for your `query` action, eg

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + '/odata/Products(:id)', {
    id: '@id' // I'm just assuming you have these default params
}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: appSettings.serverPath + '/odata/Products',
        isArray: true
    }
});
```